# I am a Lotus Notes database user and want to export some views to Excel

Tags: excel, user-interface, lotus-notes

When I do this thou not everything is getting exported -  some of the columns are marked with a green check mark and I want these marks to be exported as well.
But this seems not possible - I select the table with Ctrl+A, then right click, copy as table and in Excel Ctrl+V.

This gives me only the names of the columns in the table but not the green check mark.
Is there any way to do this such that the marks are visible in Excel?

The version I work with is Lotus Notes Standard 8.

Comment: As it stands right now, this question really belongs on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow. Notes has a feature that exports views to CSV files that Excel can read, but it might not do what you want for the column with the check mark.  (My guess is that it will export the number '82', because that is the code for a green check mark in an icon column.)

Comment: But do you have any experience with creating your own views in Notes? If you're game to try it, then you could make a personal copy of the existing view to start, and modify it to display "Yes" instead of the check mark, and then it should be easy to export it to Excel. If you can't figure out how to do that from the builtin Help in Notes and Domino Designer, then you can re-frame this as a Notes development question.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Lotusscript agent. It is actually not very hard at all.

And to make it even easier, you can use a class I wrote a while back, it will do all the work for you. You can find the class on my blog at http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

Here is how you use my class:

```
Dim csv As CSVData
Dim outfile As String

Set csv = New CSVData("DominoServer/YourDomain", "names.nsf", "People\By Last Name")
'*** Create CSV file from view
outfile = "c:\ExcelExportTest.csv"
Open outfile For Output As #1
ForAll row In csv.CSVArray()
    Print #1, row
End ForAll
Close #1
```

Easy, huh?