# Export Domino 10 view to Excel without Lotus 1-2-3

Tags: excel, export, lotus-domino, lotus

An old topic, but a new problem. I have been using Export AS 1-2-3 and saving as .wk4 file, then using the old 1-2-3 app to save as Excel. In Domino 10, that export method has been removed. I have a view with 2500 documents and hundreds of rows. I have tried for years to export as CSV, Tabular, and structured, but the data never exports totally correctly regardless of how I try to format, use the tools in Excel when opening, etc. Without a script to write to an excel file, is there no simple way to export data from a Domino view into a spreadsheet?

Comment: Have you tried Edit -> Copy as -> Table

Comment: See Karl-Henry's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832231/i-am-a-lotus-notes-database-user-and-want-to-export-some-views-to-excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get back the WK4 option by setting in the notes.ini :
**IncludeOldFileTypes=1**

True to say that "hundreds of columns" cannot be exported as easily, cause of the great size of data. It is also a kind of security... why would you not put a script, it would be so simple ?

Other ways to export data :

- Notesmanager freeware https://unplugged.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Notesmanager/summary
- NotesSQL driver (not simple)